# Safely find files matching pattern and literals

Tags: regex, bash, grep

Given a filename like 'prefix.extension', I would like to find all files of the pattern `prefix\.\d\d\.extension`. Given that 'prefix' or 'extension' could contain literal strings like `.*`, `\n` and the like, the only way I can think of finding this properly is to escape all characters in 'prefix' and 'extension', placing them before and after `\.\d\d\.`, and `egrep`-ing it. Is there a more elegant way of doing this and/or some simple way to escape all special characters for `egrep` in a Bash script?

Note that putting a backslash in front of every character will change the semantics of some, like `\w`.

Comment: not sure I understand the question, some example would be nice. How about using bashs filename globbing like "ls prefix.*.extension" ?

Comment: wouldn't globbing be so much easier than a regex for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out `grep --perl-regexp` with [`\Q` and `\E`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers) does what I need:

```
ls -1N -- "${source_dir}" | grep -P "^\Q${source_base}.\E\d\{${fragment_digits}\}\Q.${source_extensions}\E\$"
```